# Create tuple if not already one

Tags: python, tuples

How do I create a simple tuple containing a variable of any time without creating a tuple of tuples? For example a function can accept either an `int` or a `tuple` of `int`s. Inside the function I want to make sure that the variable is in fact a tuple.

So far I could think of

```
a = tuple(a)
```

and

```
a = (a,)
```

However the first one doesnt work if `a` is not iterable and the second one creates a `tuple` of a `tuple` if `a` is already one.

```
((1,2),)
```

I feel like I should be able to do that without checking the type first... What am I missing?

Comment: It might be simpler to shift the burden to the caller: require a tuple, and let the caller say `f((3,))` if there is only one `int`.

Comment: Or even simply make them vargs (`def foo(*args):`). Allows calling like `foo(3)` and `foo(1, 2)`, but it's worse if the callee already has a tuple (they'd have to call it like `foo(*the_tuple)` instead of `foo(the_tuple)`).

Comment: I think the cleanest and quickest is to just check the type, as @thefourtheye says: `a = a if isinstance(a, tuple) else (a,)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use exception handling; try calling `iter()` on the object, for example

```
try:
    iter(a)
except TypeError:
    # not an iterable, assume a single value
    a = (a,)
```

If you were planning to iterate over the tuple to handle values anyway, you just store the output of the `iter()` call and use it directly:

```
try:
    a = iter(a)
except TypeError:
    a = (a,)

for elem in a:
```

You can also make your function signature accept multiple parameters:

```
def foobar(*a):
    for elem in a:
```

Now `a` is *always* a tuple, but to pass in a tuple you'd have to call it with:

```
sometuple = (1, 2, 3)
foobar(*sometuple)
```

while a single value is passed in as:

```
foobar(singlevalue)
```

Comment: If `a` is a generator, then it will create `(<generator object ...>,)`

Comment: @thefourtheye: but the OP specified that they want to support tuples or individual values only. There are plenty of places in the Python API that require the same; a sequence, not an iterable.

Comment: But he also says `However the first one doesnt work if a is not iterable`

Comment: @thefourtheye: ah, missed that. Adjusted, the same technique applies still.

Comment: @thefourtheye: Actually, that could be read as: the error thrown by `tuple(a)` when `a` is an integer is a `TypeError` because `a` is not iterable. That doesn't mean arbitrary iterables are to be supported. But hey, my answer does now anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a lambda function:

```
a = (lambda x: x if type(x) is tuple else (x,))(a)
```

Perhaps more verbose than what you wanted, but it allows you to keep it all in one line.

Unfortunately, there's really no way to do it without checking the type of the argument. When you try to construct a tuple from another tuple - e.g.  t = (tup,) - it's treated as a generic Python object, i.e. it doesn't "know" that it's a tuple. In order for it to auto-expand the tuple, it will have to check it's type first.

A non-iterable object would also have to be identified, because it doesn't contain the necessary methods to iterate over it's elements. In other words, a non-iterable - e.g. a scalar - isn't just an iterable with a single element. They're completely different object types. It can be placed in a tuple, but not converted to one.

When you use the tuple function to create a tuple, it just treats the input as a generic iterable. It doesn't know that it's a tuple.

So whether the type check is done internally by tuple(), or by the calling function, it will still have to be done.